# Error code "Cannot assign value of type 'Void"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

Having trouble with this code to access photos in firebase database. the error I'm getting is "Cannot assign value of type 'Void?' to type 'String!'"

```
self.fileURL = metadata?.storageReference?.downloadURL(completion: error as! (URL?, Error?) -> Void)
let changeRequestPhoto = user?.user.createProfileChangeRequest()
changeRequestPhoto?.photoURL = NSURL(string: self.fileURL)! as URL
changeRequestPhoto?.commitChanges(completion: {(error) in         
    if let error = error {
        print (error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
    else {
        print ("Sweet!")
    }               
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The error says that `downloadURL` has no return value. It uses a completion handler to return data from an asynchronous task

I'm not familiar with Firebase but the syntax of the API seems to be

```
metadata?.storageReference?.downloadURL( completion: { (url, error) in
    let changeRequestPhoto = user?.user.createProfileChangeRequest()
    changeRequestPhoto?.photoURL = url
    changeRequestPhoto?.commitChanges(completion: { error in
        if let error = error {
            print (error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        else {
            print ("Sweet!")
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

On the first line, I'm assuming `self.fileURL` is the `String` you're referencing, but you are attempting to assign to it the output of `metadata?.storageReference?.downloadURL` which returns `Void`.

You'll need to grab the `url` from the completion block, as seen below. Note, this example is taken directly from [Firebase's documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#generate_a_download_url)

```
starsRef.downloadURL { url, error in
  if let error = error {
    // Handle any errors
  } else {
    // Get the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add proper completion handling for the first row

```
self.fileURL = metadata?.storageReference?.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
    if (error == nil) {
       //do something with the url
    } else {
      // error handling
    }
 })
```